# Insert data on OneToOneField using django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

I am new to this django-rest-framework, my problem is how am I going to insert a data with one-to-one relationship in the views.py.
I can do the normal way of inserting data like the one below,

```
def post(self, request,format=None):
  p = Person()
  p.firstname = "John"
  p.middlename = "K"
  p.lastname = "Rambo"
  p.save()
  e = Employee()
  e.code = "emp-002"
  e.person_id = p.id
  e.save()
```

I cannot do the approach above because I want to learn more about DRF.

To give you more idea please see below :

I have this model

```
class Person(models.Model):
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
  middlename = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
  lastname = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
class Employee(models.Model):
  person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
  code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
```

I have this serializer

```
class PersonSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ( 
      'id', 
      'firstname', 
      'middlename', 
      'lastname',)
class EmployeeSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  person = PersonSer()
  class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ('code','person')
```

I have this view

```
class SaveData(APIView):
  @transaction.atomic
  def post(self,request, format=None):
    p = PersonSer(data=request.data)
    if p.is_valid():
      p.save()
    request.data['person'] = p.data['id']
    request.data['code'] = "Emp-"+str(p.data['id'])
    """
      I expect request.data now equal to
      {
        'person' : 102, # we assume the newly created person id == 102
        'code' : 'Emp-102',
        'firstname' : 'John',
        'middlename' : 'K.',
        'lastname' : 'Rambo'
      }
    """

    es = EmployeeSer(data=request.data)
    if es.is_valid():
      es.save()
    else:
      print(es.errors) # {'person': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
    """
    I also tried this,
    es = EmployeeSer(data={'person' : p.data, 'code' : 'Sample code'})
    if es.is_valid():
      es.save()
    else:
      print(es.errors) #{'person': {'fullname': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.',code='blank')], ]}}
    """
    return Response({'message':'okay'})
```

The request.data is a formData, the value is

```
{
  'firstname' : 'John',
  'middlename' : 'K.',
  'lastname' : 'Rambo'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the create method of the PersonSer to achieve this.

```
class PersonSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  ...
  def create(self, validated_data):
      person = Person.objects.create(**validated_data)
      Employee.objects.create(person=person, code=f"Emp-{person.id}")
      return person
```

And you can simplify your view to:

```
...
@transaction.atomic
  def post(self,request, format=None):
    p = PersonSer(data=request.data)
    p.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    p.save()
    return Response({'message':'okay'})
...
```

`raise_expection=True` will cause serializer to raise `ValidationError` exception if there are validation errors.

Comment: I can do this without changing the definition of EmployeeSer?

Comment: Yes. You can do this without changing the definition of employeeSer. Here we are just changing how person and employee are created. The create method is automatically (internally) called by serialiser when we call save().

Comment: I tried your code but the error occured, it says:  type object 'EmployeeSer' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: My bad. It should be employee the model, mistakenly wrote employeeSer. I have updated the answer. You can check it again

Comment: is it posible to do pass another data on validated_data that is not existed on fields?

Comment: Yes that's possible. You can simply define fields serializer type in serializer, say 'field1' = serializer.CharField() and include this field in the class Meta: fields = (...,"field1")

Comment: it works but I got an error if its a foriegn key. eg. one table pointing on multiple table.

Comment: Share the error, I will try to help you with it